# Newbie OpenACC issue with CYCLE instruction in Fortran

Tags: openacc

quite newbie with OpenACC here, so please be patient :-)

I'm trying to port some Fortran code to use OpenACC, and I'm finding a strange (at least to me) behaviour.

The code is given below, but as you can see is just some nested loops which ultimately update the variable zc, which I copyout. I have tried to make private copies where I think they are needed and for the moment specified that all loops are independent. Now, when I compile with and without OpenACC all is fine if I remove the line "if(mu2-mup2.ne.q2) cycle", but if that line is present, then the results for the zc calculated with OpenACC are very different to those calculated without OpenACC.

Any ideas why that line could be giving me trouble?

Many thanks in advance,
Ángel de Vicente

```
  !$acc data copyout(zc)
  !$acc update device(fact)
  !$acc kernels
  !$acc loop independent private(k2)
  do k=kmin,kmax
     k2=2*k
     !$acc loop independent private(km,kp2,z0)
     do kp=kmin,kmax
        km = MIN(k,kp)
        kp2=2*kp
        z0=3.d0*dble(ju2+1)*dsqrt(dble(k2+1))*dsqrt(dble(kp2+1))
        !$acc loop independent private(q2)
        do q=-km,km
           q2=2*q
           !$acc loop independent
           do mu2=-ju2,ju2,2
              !$acc loop independent private(p2,z1)
              do ml2=-jl2,jl2,2
                 p2=mu2-ml2
                 if(iabs(p2).gt.2) cycle
                 z1=w3js(ju2,jl2,2,mu2,-ml2,-p2)
                 !$acc loop independent private(pp2,z2)
                 do mup2=-ju2,ju2,2
                    if(mu2-mup2.ne.q2) cycle
                    pp2=mup2-ml2
                    if(iabs(pp2).gt.2) cycle
                    z2=w3js(ju2,jl2,2,mup2,-ml2,-pp2)
                    !$acc loop independent
                    do mlp2=-jl2,jl2,2
                       zc(ml2,mlp2,mu2,mup2,k,kp,q) = z2
                    enddo
                 enddo
              enddo
           enddo
        end do
     end do
  end do
  !$acc end kernels
  !$acc end data
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a reproducing example it's difficult to give a complete answer, but I'll do my best.

First, there are only three parallel dimensions in OpenACC: gang, worker, and vector.  Hence, the compiler will need to ignore 4 of the 7 loop directives.  Most likely the middle 4 (if using PGI, you can see which loops the compiler is parallelizing from the compiler feedback messages, i.e. -Minfo=accel).  Not that you can't parallelize all the loops, but you'd need to make them tightly nested and then use the collapse clause to collapse them into a single parallel loop.

Also since scalars are private by default, there's no need to put them into a private clause (except for a few cases).  While putting them in a private clause shouldn't impact correctness, it can cause performance slow downs since you'd be fetching the private copy from global memory rather than having the potential of the scalar being put into a register.

My guess is that the inner loops are not that large so may not be beneficial to parallelize.  Hence, I would first try removing all the inner "loop" directives, and only parallelize the "k" and "kp" loops.  Depending of the values of "kmin" and "kmax", I'd try collapsing them as well.  Something like:

```
  !$acc loop independent collapse(2)
  do k=kmin,kmax
     do kp=kmin,kmax
        k2=2*k
        km = MIN(k,kp)
```

Assuming that gets you the correct answers but not as much parallelism as you want, you can then try collapsing the middle two loops:

```
    !$acc loop independent collapse(2)
    do q=-km,km
       do mu2=-ju2,ju2,2
          q2=2*q
          do ml2=-jl2,jl2,2
```

I wouldn't recommend parallelizing loops with cycles in them.  Not that you can't, but doing so would hurt performance due to thread divergence.

If none of this helps, please post a full reproducing example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You can get a minimal version of my code at: git clone https://angelv@bitbucket.org/angelv/so_openacc.git  Now, the cycle's are not an issue anymore (at least in term of correctness), and I will look into optimizing the code with the collapse option, etc. Now, I'm trying to understand when private clauses are needed. In the code as you download it, the results from running with/without OpenACC are identical, but if I remove the private(k2) clase from the first loop the results is different... Do you know of a place where I can read about the rules for private variables?

Comment: I was able to grab the code.  Ok, this is one of the cases where you do need to manually privatize these scalars.  The reason is because these are module data members with static storage.  So when you update the scalar, the compiler must make it a global reference by default.  You can fix this by making the scalars local to the subroutine.  Other cases when you need to manually privatize scalars are when they are passed by address to a subroutine (default in Fortran).  In this case, it's recommended to use the F2003 "value" attribute to pass the scalars by value.